# Unable to render content with React-Konva

Tags: reactjs, react-dom, konvajs, react-konva

I've recently been getting the following error when trying to render a `Stage` with React-Konva: `Cannot read property 'getPooled' of null at Object.componentDidMount`. As of now, I've been unable to render anything at all using Konva. I'm using react-konva with typescript and webpack.
The following is my simplified code:

---

.jsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Layer, Stage, Rect, Group } from 'react-konva';

class Demo extends React.Component {

public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <div style={{flex: 5}}>
            <Stage width={320} height={320} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
                <Layer>
                   <Rect
                        height={32}
                        width={32}
                        x={0}
                        y={0}
                        fill={'#bb66bb'}
                    />
                </Layer>
            </Stage>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

I've tracked down the issue to **this line** in the **react-konva source code**
`var transaction = ReactUpdates.ReactReconcileTransaction.getPooled();`
Which I have (I believe) traced to the following code in `ReactUpdates` (which is part of `react-dom`).

```
var ReactUpdates = {
/**
* React references `ReactReconcileTransaction` using this property in order
* to allow dependency injection.
*
* @internal
*/
ReactReconcileTransaction: null,
...ommitted code here for brevity
};

module.exports = ReactUpdates;
```

Obviously, the referenced property is set to `null`...I just don't really understand why `react-konva` is referencing this property, or if i'm just misreading what's happening. Any ideas?
(Also, I'm using `v. 1.1.4 of react-konva` and `v. 15.5.4 of react-dom`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the issue! It was something in `webpack.config.js`

```
externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
    "canvas": "canvas"
}
```

All need to be disabled, and it worked like a charm (no idea why, unfortunately).

Comment: Cheers for posting the solution.